# SELECT from 2 tables using a JOIN and compare column value from one table to count of other table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from 2 tables using a JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*, COUNT(b.*) as num_topups FROM customer_sms a JOIN customer_sms_topups b ON a.sequence = b.sms_account WHERE a.sequence = b.sms_account AND a.auto_topup_credits > '0' AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance AND MONTH(b.datetime) = '10' AND YEAR(b.datetime) = '2018' AND num_topups < a.auto_topup_maximum;
```

But i think i have the count wrong:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) as num_topups FROM customer_sms a JOIN customer_sms_topups b ON a.sequence = ' at line 1
```

I need the count to compare the number of rows in customer_sms_topups to `a.auto_topup_maximum`

Comment: use `COUNT(*)` not `COUNT(b.*)`

Comment: tried that and it says column `num_topups` is unknown

Comment: that is different issue, because you cannot use an alias in the where condition. what exactly are you trying to achieve using this query

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I need compare the number of rows in `customer_sms_topups` to `a.auto_topup_maximum`

Comment: then you should get the number of rows in customer_sms_topus in a correlated subquery.

Comment: Please do this: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the count you should use count(*)

but you have others column in select not involved in aggregation function and not mentioned  in group by
this is depreacted in  SQL don't work in most of the db and dpn't work in th most recent  version of mysql

for the version  where this work the resul for this columns in unpredictable
so you should 
or use explict column name in select and add  a proper group by clause  eg:

```
SELECT a.col1
      , a.col2  
        , COUN(T*) as num_topups 
FROM customer_sms a 
JOIN customer_sms_topups b ON a.sequence = b.sms_account 
WHERE a.sequence = b.sms_account 
AND a.auto_topup_credits > '0' 
AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance 
AND MONTH(b.datetime) = '10' 
AND YEAR(b.datetime) = '2018'
group by a.col1 , a.col2
```

or use aggregation function for all the columns you are selecting

```
SELECT min(a.col1)
      , min(a.col2  )
        , COUNT(*) as num_topups 
FROM customer_sms a 
JOIN customer_sms_topups b ON a.sequence = b.sms_account 
WHERE a.sequence = b.sms_account 
AND a.auto_topup_credits > '0' 
AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance 
AND MONTH(b.datetime) = '10' 
AND YEAR(b.datetime) = '2018'
```

Comment: whats `col1` and `col2`?

Comment: are a sample for explicit columns ..name  .. have your read  deeply the answer ?? .. you should change col1, col2  ,, with your real columns name and use this also in group by

Comment: in your example, you have counted the rows in `customer_sms` but i need the count for `customer_sms_topups`

Comment: in sql  you can count the rows  returned form the query  .. od you can count the number of istance of not null value in column or the number of distinct value of a column  .. if you want count the number of a separated table then  count and join the result

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate expressions can be compared in a `HAVING` clause, but are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause.

And we usually have a `GROUP BY` clause in a query with an aggregate, unless we want to collapse the result into a single row.

Without an actual specification, illustrated with example data and expected result, we're just guessing what result the query should return.

My guess is that we're after the result that would be returned by this query:

```
SELECT a.*
     , COUNT(b.sms_account) AS num_topups
  FROM customer_sms a

  LEFT
  JOIN customer_sms_topups b
    ON b.sms_account = a.sequence
   AND b.datetime   >= '2018-10-01' 
   AND b.datetime    < '2018-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH

 WHERE a.auto_topup_credits > '0'
   AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance

 GROUP
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...

HAVING COUNT(b.sms_account) < a.auto_topup_maximum

 ORDER
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...
```

---

If we want to exclude rows that have a "zero" for `num_topups`, we can remove the `LEFT` keyword.

There are several other query patterns to return an equivalent result.

For example, conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT a.*
     , SUM(IF(b.datetime >= '2018-10-01' AND b.datetime < '2018-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
           ,1,0)
       ) AS num_topups
  FROM customer_sms a
  LEFT
  JOIN customer_sms_topups b
    ON b.sms_account = a.sequence
 WHERE a.auto_topup_credits > '0'
   AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance

 GROUP
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...

HAVING num_topups < a.auto_topup_maximum

 ORDER
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...
```

---

Or we can do aggregation in an inline view, and then do the join. With this pattern, we can avoid a GROUP BY clause on the outer query.

```
SELECT a.*
     , c.num_topups
  FROM customer_sms a
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT b.sms_account   AS sms_account
              , SUM(1)          AS num_topups
           FROM customer_sms_topups b
          WHERE b.datetime   >= '2018-10-01' 
            AND b.datetime    < '2018-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
          GROUP
             BY b.sms_account
       ) c
    ON c.sms_account = a.sequence
   AND IFNULL(c.num_topups,0) < a.auto_topup_maximum

 WHERE a.auto_topup_credits > '0'
   AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance

 ORDER
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...
```

---

A correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list can also be used to get a count. By avoiding the join to the child table, we can get a count of related rows without needing a `GROUP BY` clause in the outer query:

```
SELECT a.*
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
           FROM customer_sms_topups b
          WHERE b.sms_account = a.sequence 
            AND b.datetime   >= '2018-10-01' 
            AND b.datetime    < '2018-10-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
       ) AS num_topups
  FROM customer_sms a
 WHERE a.auto_topup_credits > '0'
   AND a.auto_topup_threshold <= a.balance

HAVING num_topups < a.auto_topup_maximum

 ORDER
    BY a.sequence
     , a.auto_topup_credits
     , a.auto_topup_threshold
     , a.balance
     , ...
```